# URI Parameter validation in MCS/nodejs

Tags: node.js, mcs

Need your help to solve a problem . I am writing a custom API in MCS with method type as "`GET`" , passing the parameter along with the URI .

```
service.get('/mobile/custom/****/deviceVersion/:deviceType',function(req,res){
    var reqParams = req.params;
    var finalResponse;
    var params='/'+reqParams.deviceType;
    console.info("Request Params>"+params);
    if(reqParams.deviceType=='{}'){     // ***Here is my problem***
        finalResponse = jbuilder.encode(function (json) {
                     json.set('Response', function (json) {
                          json.set('responseCode', '400');
                          json.set('responseMessage', 'Malformed request query');
                     });

                });
            res.status(400).send(finalResponse);
            res.end();

    }else{
        //console.info("In Else and length=>"+reqParams.deviceType+"//"+reqParams.deviceType.length);
        //var params='/'+reqParams.deviceType;
        var connector='/deviceVersion';
        commonHandler.CommonHandlerGetMethodFunction(req,res,connector,params);
    }

});
```

In my case i have to check whether the parameter `deviceType` is null or not .

I have tried the following methods

```
 1. if(reqParams.deviceType=='{}'){}

 2. if(JSON.Stringify(reqParams.deviceType)=='{}'){}

 3. if(JSON.Stringify(reqParams.deviceType).length==0){}
```

Could anyone please tell me the right approach for the validation against null ?
Thanks in Advance

### Updated

The error i am getting while passing `deviceType` as null is

```
{
    "type": "w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
    "status": 404,
    "title": "API not found",
    "detail": "We cannot find the API ******/1.0 for the provided URL path /deviceVersion/. Verify your request parameters and try again.",
    "o:ecid": "005Hp2YhoPF3j4C_nDs1yZ000Uba00001w, 0:3",
    "o:errorCode": "MOBILE-57945",
    "o:errorPath": "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/"
 }
```

Endpoint given in MCS Custom Api is `/deviceVersion/{deviceType}`

Comment: i am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was cross posted to the Oracle OTN MCS forum and answered there: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4012301

Comment: Thanks @Chris . My friend was posted there .

Answer (score 0):

`if (!req.params.deviceType)` should work.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error




{
  "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
  "status": 404,
  "title": "API not found",
  "detail": "We cannot find the API ******/1.0 for the provided URL path /deviceVersion/. Verify your request parameters and try again.",
  "o:ecid": "005Hp2YhoPF3j4C_nDs1yZ000Uba00001w, 0:3",
  "o:errorCode": "MOBILE-57945",
  "o:errorPath": "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/"
}